# Busboy and GridFS won't save file to filesystem

Tags: javascript, node.js

When the following POST API is called, it should save the file to the file system. However, the file is not being saved. I can see the file in the console, but can't save/write it.
I have the following code:

```
router.post('/notes', function(req, res, next) {
  var gfsstream, startFileWrite, endFileWriteTime;
  var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    startFileWrite = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);

    gfsstream = gfs.createWriteStream('/uploads');
    file.on('data', function(data) {
      gfsstream.write(data);
    });
    file.on('end', function() {
      gfsstream.end();
      req.pipe(gfsstream);
    });
    gfsstream.on('close', function (file) {
      // do something with `file`
     endFileWrite = new Date().getTime();
     console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
     console.log("Time needed: " + (endFileWrite - startFileWrite) + " ms");
    });
  });

  busboy.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.sendStatus(500, 'ERROR', err);
  });

  busboy.on('finish', function end() {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
  req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

`req.pipe(gfsstream)` might be the issue here, but I am not sure what is preventing the file from being saved.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `file.pipe(gfsstream)` and use the `finish` event instead of the `close` event:

```
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  startFileWrite = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename);

  gfsstream = gfs.createWriteStream('/uploads');
  file.pipe(gfsstream).on('finish', function() {
    endFileWrite = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
    console.log("Time needed: " + (endFileWrite - startFileWrite) + " ms");
  });
});
```